# Convert Date string to Date " Not Hard coded Date "

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

1) the below code fetch data from several sheets in a folder and combine all date in one sheet.

2) in this combined sheet tab that have max date function.

```
var maxDate = SS.getRange("MaxDate!A1").getValue();
```

3) the sheets in the folder have date and time format like this 
`08-09-2019 10:59 AM`.

4) i made the script loop all sheet and compare the date in those sheets with the max date function in the combined sheet and if the date greater than max date then fetch those data so basically it fetches the most recent data.

5) the problem is when i do the below code it read that date `08-09-2019 10:59 AM` as string and return `1970-00-01`, I tried to put the date variable inside `new Date();` to convert it to date but I still have the same issue and when I remove the `new Date();` it give me the error `can't find method formatDate(string, string, string)`.

**So I need help to convert this date variable `fileDate` to actual date**

```js
fileHeaders = fileSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, fileSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

```js
dateCol = fileHeaders[0].indexOf('Creation date and time')+1;
```

```js
fileDate = new Date(fileSheet.getRange(2,dateCol,1,1).getValue());
```

```js
dateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(fileDate, "GMT+2", "yyyy-mm-dd");
```

```js
function combineData() {  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("17eFdVXdVE3sxemcC_qO0QfY71zKU4YLh");
  var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var maxDate = SS.getRange("MaxDate!A1").getValue();
  var rDS = SS.getSheetByName('Raw Data');
  var oriColHeaders = rDS.getRange(1, 1, 1, SS.getSheetByName('Raw Data').getMaxColumns()).getValues();

  var file;
  var filetype;
  var fileDate;
  var dateFormat;
  var ssID;
  var combinedData = [];
  var data;
  var columnsHeaders;
  var colindex;

  while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
    file = filesIterator.next();    
    filetype = file.getMimeType();
    var fileSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets()[0];
    var fileHeaders = fileSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, fileSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol = fileHeaders[0].indexOf('Creation date and time')+1;

    fileDate = new Date(fileSheet.getRange(2,dateCol,1,1).getValue());
    dateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(fileDate, "GMT+2", "yyyy-mm-dd");
    Logger.log(dateFormat);

    if(filetype === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" && dateFormat > maxDate) {
      ssID = file.getId();
      columnsHeaders = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0].getMaxColumns()).getValues();

      for (var i = columnsHeaders[0].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        if (oriColHeaders[0].indexOf(columnsHeaders[0][i]) === -1) {          

          SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets()[0].deleteColumn(i+1);          
        }
    }
    data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0].getRange("A2:AG" + SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0].getLastRow()).getValues();
    combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);      
  }
  var activeWS = SS.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var activeWSLR = activeWS.getRange("S1:S").getValues().filter(String).length;

  if(combinedData.length > 0) {    
    activeWS.getRange(activeWSLR+1, 1, combinedData.length, combinedData[0].length).setValues(combinedData).sort(19);
  }
  else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No new files.')
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This appears to be a bug!

According to the Apps Script Documentation, other than for the Contacts service:

> Dates used elsewhere in App Script use JavaScript's standard [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

Using the JavaScript console of your web browser, you can see that parsing `08-09-2019 10:59 AM` into `new Date("08-09-2019 10:59 AM");` returns correctly:

```text
Fri Aug 09 2019 10:59:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

As a result, I have filed a bug on Google's Issue Tracker detailing this. You can find the issue report [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143065963) and you can click the ☆ in the top left to let Google know that you are experiencing the issue too.

#### Workaround:

For now, as long as your dates are all of the same format, you can convert the date into a format that is defined in the Date Constructor of the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```js
function parseDate(date) {
  var parts = date.split(" ");
  var datePart = parts[0].split("-");
  var timePart = parts[1];
  var amPm = parts[2];
  
  if (amPm == "PM") {
    var temp = timePart.split(":");
    timePart = (parseInt(temp[0]) + 12).toString() + ":" + temp[1];
  }
  return new Date(datePart[2] + "-" + datePart[0] + "-" + datePart[1] + "T" + timePart + ":00");
}
```

#### Usage:

Instead of using

```js
fileDate = new Date(fileSheet.getRange(2, dateCol, 1, 1).getValue());
```

You can use:

```js
fileDate = parseDate(fileSheet.getRange(2, dateCol, 1, 1).getValue());
```

#### References:

- [Class `DateField` of Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/date-field)
- [`Date` object - MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)